# recursive typedef

Tags: c++, typedef, recursion

Is the following allowed?

```
typedef Foo<Bar> Bar;
```

My compiler complains that 'class Bar' has a previous declaration as 'class Bar'.

Comment: why would one think it makes sense to do that?

Comment: Consider a state machine where each state function returns a pointer to the next function to execute. The types of such functions are recursive. You can express this with classes (struct StateFunction { StateFunction operator()(void* context); };) but not with, say, raw functions or typedefs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is the equivalent of:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};
typedef A B;
```

which not suprisingly is not legal.

Comment: Typedefs and classes are not in different namespaces in C++, thus it's not legal in C++.

Answer (score 2):

If Bar is a class as a template parameter for Foo, it can't be the typedefed `Foo<Bar>` at the same time.
You would be redeclaring Bar, first as a standalone class and then as a template instantiation, but even `typedef Foo<Whatever> Bar;` wouldn't work if you have already declared Bar as a class.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not allowed.